# Why isnt the <required> attribute on my checkbox working despite having set up some JS code making this a requirement?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Right, why is it still possible to send off the `html` form I have created without the need to check the Privacy Policy consent `checkbox`, despite having JS code requiring the user that this `checkbox` needs to be checked for the form to be submitted?

My browser is Edge.

Heres the code:

```js
#agreeCheckbox{
 position: absolute;
 display: inline;
 margin-left: 5px;
 margin-bottom: 12000px;
 padding:5px;
 background-color: white;
}
#agreeCheckbox {
  display: none;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
input + .label-text:before{
 content:"\f046 ";
 font-family: Fontawesome;
 margin-right: 5px;
 display: inline-block;
 width: 1em;
 font-size: 15px;
 line-height: 1;
 font-weight: normal;
 font-style: normal;
 font-variant: normal;
}
input:checked + .label-text:before{
 content: "\f096 ";
 font-family: Fontawesome;
 line-height: 1;
 font-weight: normal;
 font-style: normal;
 font-variant: normal;
 font-size: 15px;
}
.label-text{
 font-size: 15px;
    color: #FFF;
    font-weight: normal!important;
    cursor: pointer!important;
}
.no-content:after{
 content: "";
 margin-top:5px;
    
}
```

```css
<script>
function consentValidation() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myCheck").required;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "You must consent to our Privacy Policy before submitting this form.";
}
</script>
```

```html
<form method="post" action="../php/services-interest-form.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">

                                    <p class="legal-section-title" style="color: #FFF!important;">Privacy Notice</p>
                                    <p style="color: #FFF!important;">We want you to know how our service works and why we need your registration details. Please read our <a href="../pages/privacy policy.html">Privacy Policy</a> and then tick below that you agree with it.</p><br/>
                                    <label class="no-content" style="display: inline;">
                                        <input name="agreePP" id="myCheck" type="checkbox" value="true" required />
                                        <span class="label-text">I accept and agree to the Privacy Policy*</span>
                                        <p id="demo" class="label-text" style="color:red!important;">You must consent to our Privacy Policy before submitting this form.</p>
                                    </label>
                                </div><br/>
                                <input onClick="consentValidation()" class="std_button" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
                            </form>
```

In addition to this, why when I remove the `checked` attribute, is the default state of the checkbox checked and vice-versa. When I insert the `checked` attribute, the default state remains unchecked?

This is also a custom css `checkbox` hence why mines a little more complicated than most. Sorry about that however, this is a consent to our Privacy Policy so this need to be 100% correct for obvious reasons.

It's getting beyond a joke to be honest but if anyone can shed some light onto this then that would be great.

Thanks

Comment: Your function currently serves no purpose. Currently, the variable `x` is never referenced, and the user will always get the validation error. You should also listen on the submit event of the form, not the click event of a button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simple. You should wrap them in form element:

```
<form>
...
</form>
```

And other attributes you may need like action, method. Check the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form).

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your inputs in a form for it to work. Here's your updated code

```
<form>
    <label class="no-content" style="display: inline;">
      <input name="agreePP" id="myCheck" type="checkbox" value="agreePP" required>
      <span class="label-text">I accept and agree to the Privacy Policy*</span>
      <p id="demo" class="label-text" style="color:red!important;"></p>
    </label>
    <input onClick="consentValidation()" class="std_button" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Yes, sorry, this as wrapped in a <form? attribute

Comment: Your html has to be inside the `<form>` tag for the attribute `required` to work